# Error while installing modules in Pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, module, installation, pycharm

In Pycharm(Version 18.2.7) I opened a terminal and entered command

```
pip install numpy
```

for installing numpy module.

After pressing enter execution is :

```
    Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/6f/24647f014eef9b67a24adfcbcd4f4928349b4a0f8393b3d7fe648d4d2de3/numpy-1.16.6.zip
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\She
tty\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hquqxd6z\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close(
);exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Shetty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4k3vafer\install-record.txt --single-version-exter
nally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\include\site\python3.4\numpy:
    Running from numpy source directory.
```

```
Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

blis_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Shetty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hquqxd6z\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
blas_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Shetty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hquqxd6z\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Shetty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hquqxd6z\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
customize MSVCCompiler
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\Shetty\\PycharmProjects\\trial\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Shetty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hquqxd6z\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\Shetty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hquqxd6z\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  self.calc_info()
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win32-3.4
creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy
creating build\src.win32-3.4\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

----------------------------------------
```

after code execution it says:

```
    Command "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local
p\\pip-install-hquqxd6z\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code
ile__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4k3vafer\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --com
--install-headers C:\Users\Shetty\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\include\site\python3.4\numpy" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Shetty\AppData\Local\
pip-install-hquqxd6z\numpy\
```

I think some error occurred. How should i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try Downloading Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0. According to your error, you can get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279